# Filter pouchdb docs on the list by ID from another doc - two promises in sequence

Tags: angularjs, angular, pouchdb

I've got two types of docs in pouchdb:

- todos - list of todos
- user - just user number put in pochdb by separate form

When I write todos I also have variable for userNo. This way I know which todos he owns.
I've got two functions in provider to get todos, and user number.

In html list I want to filter todos by user number through pipe:

```
<ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let todo of todos | filter : 'numer_p' : this.todoService.userNo">
```

If I enter this number by hand it works great. Todos are filtered by this number.

The problem is that I have two calls in home.ts ionViewLoaded:

```
    //call provider to get all docs to show on the list
this.todoService.getTodos().then((data) => {
this.todos = data;
});

//call provider to get userNo from pouchdb and set variable in the provider
this.todoService.getUser().then((result) => {
    console.log("getBadacz result:" + JSON.stringify(result));
    this.todoService.userNo = result['name'];
}).then(function(second){;
    console.log("second");
});
```

**I need to call getTodos AFTER getUser. So I need to run this functions in sequence using Promises.**
Without it this.todoService.userNo in filter is undefined, because it is not set yet. And it will not work.

I tried to do it like this:

```
    this.todoService.getUser().then((result) => {
    console.log("getBadacz result:" + JSON.stringify(result));
    this.todoService.userNo = result['name'];
}).then(function(second){;
    console.log("second");
    this.todoService.getTodos().then((data) => {
        this.todos = data;
    });
});
```

But there is an error:

```
EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'todoService' of null
```

I tried to arrange this promises in sequence but without success.

Here is fiddle where you can find implementation of functions in provider:
[Filter pouchdb docs by userID saved in another doc](https://jsfiddle.net/30yua2jx/)

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Is it angular2? Try to remove `this.` from `this.todoService.userNo` in your html template

Comment: I thought it was about "rush" problem. It seems I over-complicated this :) Thanks! It works.

Answer (score 0):

In situation like this, I would try to include userId in the todo key, that would increase performance (a todos document may have key like this `userId_todoId`).

So you will not need two promises at all.